# How to denote a one to one mapping between $A = \{ B,C,D\}$ and $B = \{ {X_1},{X_2},{X_3}\}$?

Tags: notation

How to denote there exist a one to one mapping with **order** between the set $A = \{ B,C,D\}$ and the set $B = \{ {X_1},{X_2},{X_3}\}$ ?

Particularly, the result will be like this:

$\begin{gathered}
  B = {X_1} \hfill \\
  C = {X_2} \hfill \\
  D = {X_3} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$

Is there any way to write this compactly instead of listing each and every element like this because sometime the cardinal of both sets can be large.

Please help me,

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, and what you mean by "mapping with order". But in general, to specify a mapping $\mathcal A \to \mathcal B$ you must either explicitly specify how to map the elements, for example $B\mapsto X_1,C\mapsto X_2,D\mapsto X_3$, or you specify a term $E(x)$ depending on a variable $x$ so that $E(x)\in\mathcal B$, and you would write $x\mapsto E(x)$.

Comment: When I said mapping with order I want to describe that $\begin{gathered}
  A = \{ B > C > D\}  \hfill \\
  B = \{ {X_1} > {X_2} > {X_3}\}  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

so the following will occur $\begin{gathered}
  B = {X_1} \hfill \\
  C = {X_2} \hfill \\
  D = {X_3} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$

Is there any way to say that $B,C,D = {X_1},{X_2},{X_3}$ without explicitly list out the mapping of each element ?

Comment: What kind of ordering do you have on your sets? In the event that they are well ordered, then each set uniquely corresponds to an ordinal.

Comment: Thank you , the order is just like the comment above.